# api.weather.gov start and end times

Tags: php, json

I've been using the alerts feature from the relatively new V3 API from **weather.gov**. I have been successfully using the API to view current alerts at https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active using PHP with the appropriate accept, version and user-agent headers being sent in the HTTP request.

I'm now looking to expand this to allow querying for inactive alerts for a specific date. The documentation spells out start and end parameters in `ISO8601DateTime` format. Thus the following example URL should produce a list of all alerts on May 15, 2018 in Illinois:

https://api.weather.gov/alerts?start=2018-05-14T00:00:00-05:00&end=2018-05-15T00:00:00-05:00&state=IL

However this produces the response:

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [],
   "title": "Watches, warnings, and advisories issued between Mon, May 14, 2018 12:00:00 AM -0500 and Tue, May 14, 2018 12:00:00 AM -0500 for Illinois"
}
```

The response makes it clear that the parameters are being parsed correctly. And I know there were plenty of alerts issued this day throughout Illinois. I have also tried plenty of variations of shorter and longer duration, different time zones (including none), different dates and different states, including no state provided. All of them provide similar results describing the list, but no actual data.

Has anyone found better documentation on the API or otherwise had success with the alert start and end times?

You can find the (in)complete documentation of the API [here](https://forecast-v3.weather.gov/documentation).

Answer (score 2):

I played around and eventually just looked at what you get back with one simple request for anything in IL.

https://api.weather.gov/alerts?state=IL

Then I used effective instead of start and end.

https://api.weather.gov/alerts?state=IL&effective=2018-05-20T06:08:00-04:00

You get some things back:

```
    {
        "@context": [
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geojson/geojson-ld/master/contexts/geojson-base.jsonld",
    {
        "wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#",
        "@vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#"
    }
],
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-2847567-2622897",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -90.97,
                        39.39
                    ],
                    [
                        -90.89,
                        39.45
                    ],
                    [
                        -90.77,
                        39.38
                    ],
                    [
                        -90.71,
                        39.23
                    ],
                    [
                        -90.81,
                        39.22
                    ],
                    [
                        -90.97,
                        39.39
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Both of the queries you suggest, with and without the "effective" parameter, return identical results. The results date from 5/15/2018 until today, so it's not really filtering by "effective".

Comment: I wasn't trying to filter. I was trying to help you ascertain what is needed to query. Try some of the combinations of "sent"               "effective"  "onset" "expires" or "ends"

Answer (score 1):

I revisited this not long ago and it's clear that something changed under the hood at NWS as I can now get responses with start and end times specified. First for the timestamps:

- The time is formatted ISO-8601 with several quirks as follows. Keep in mind that all of the following are valid ISO-8601.
- These formats work

  - `2020-05-14T05:40:08-00:00`
  - `2020-05-14T05:40:08-05:00` Changed offset to -5 hours
  - `2020-05-14T05:40:08Z` Changed time zone to Z (shorthand for UTC)
- These do not work

  - `2020-05-14T05:40:08+00:00` No positive offsets are accepted
  - `2020-05-14T05:40:08.000Z` Milliseconds are not accepted
  - `20200514T054008Z` Without punctuation is not accepted
  - `2020-05-14` Dates only are not accepted

Here's a URL that will return data until about 5/21/2020: https://api.weather.gov/alerts?start=2020-05-14T05:40:08-00:00

I also learned the following:

- The `start` and `end` url parameters appear to be filtering the `sent` field in the responses.
- The `/alerts` endpoint has data for approximately the last week.